# Access VBA script isn't successfully passing variable to Text Box field in Report

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to pass a simple variable to a text box on a report via `VBA`.

I've done research, and seen things like using `Me.fieldName = value`, but I get the keyword error trying to do that. So instead I tried to use the Where portion of the `OpenReport` and that doesn't seem to fly either.

What happens is the code requests the input as expected, then opens the report, which then asks for the parameter anyway, even though it should be receiving it from the string.

I know I'm missing something, but my eyes aren't seeing it. Please help me undo my idiocy.

Current Relevant code:

```
Dim Message, Title, Default, MyValue
Message = "Please enter test variation (A, B, C, etc)"
Title = "Test Variation"
Default = ""
MyValue = InputBox(Message, Title, Default)
DoCmd.OpenReport "Random_Test", acViewPreview, , "TestNum=" & MyValue
```

Edit: For clarity: 
`Random_Test` is the report I'm populating. On that report is a single `Text Box` type field named `TestNum`.
The `MyValue` InputBox is supposed to accept user input to make `MyValue` mean something, which (as I understand it) should be passed via the `Where` portion of the `OpenReport` call.

I can manually enter the data at the parameter, but I don't want to have to do that, particularly if I need to generate multiple files quickly.

Comment: I've even tried setting up a function that calls the variable, and setting the text box to that function, and that hasn't worked either.

Comment: Is TestNum a text type field? If yes, try: `TestNum='" & MyValue & "'"`. Access can't find TestNum - are you sure it is field in the report RecordSource? Is the report properly filtered when it opens? Is there a dynamic parameter in the report RecordSource?

Comment: Answerable "why isn't this code working?" questions **require** a [mcve].

Comment: @June7 Yeah, it's a text box type field.  Adjusted the code to match.  No change.

Per your example, looks like this:
`DoCmd.OpenReport "Random_Test", acViewPreview, , "TestNum = '" & MyValue & "'"`

Comment: Did you see questions in my earlier comment?

Comment: I did, but only after I sent my reply.

There's no field named TestNum or anything it's referencing in any of my tables.  My intent was that the box would only be filled from user input, rather than any other way (though I'm seriously considering automating the damned thing).

The reference source for the report itself shows as a query joining my two tables. There's no control source on that field, at this point, though.  I tried pointing it to a function that called the variable, but that didn't pan out (even after trying to set the variable as global).

... (part 2 inc)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by properly filtered to be honest.  All data populates in the report without issue, but that's a data pull from the table.  Interestingly, I did find TestNum = 'A' in the Filter field in the report properties, so it turns out the report *is* getting the info.  I'm just clearly passing it wrong.

Bear with me, I've been doing VBA all of 3 days now, so I may be unfamiliar with some of your asks.

Comment: The 'Where' field filters the underlying query. Me.fieldname is a property of 'Me', and depends on what 'Me' is.  In old versions of MSAccess properties were automatically created for some objects which are NOT automatically given properties in current versions of MSAccess: this can be trap reading old examples. After opening the report, you can set the value of a textbox by external code, but it is often easier to do so inside one of the report events, so that the event fires at the correct point. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The code is the final report generation for creating a randomized multiple choice test. Since multiple tests could be created, I needed to be able to match a test to the answer key.  The input was to create that identifier. Kostas' info below helped get that working. My eventual goal is to automate even that so that the user can simply indicate how many tests they want, and it will iterate automatically. That's for another day, however, as I now have to learn forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the argument in .OpenArgs property and capture it when the report loads.

Pass to .OpenArgs:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "Random_Test", acViewPreview, , , acWindowNormal, "TestNum=" & MyValue
```

Capture on the report's Load event:

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
    With Me
        If Not IsNull(.OpenArgs) Then
            .TestNum.Value = .OpenArgs
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That report load event was exactly what I was missing.  I did have to change the OpenArg segment to just be `MyValue` but now it's working perfectly.

Thank you so much.